# Select top 100 with all available combination of records in SQL Server with running total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have say 5000 records in a table with 20 unique ClientId's. How can I select 100 records in which all 20 unique clientId's are covered.

In SQL Server

Edit: Also how can I have a running total column in the same query

For ex there are 5 unique names

```
Id.    Name. Amt. total
5.      Abc.    10.    10
3.      Def.      20.    30
6.      Xxx.      5.      35
2.       You.     10.    45
1.       Fed.     20.    65
5.       Abc.      5.     70
3.       Def.       12.   82
.................
```

Comment: SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, etc?

Comment: This question is quite clear as proven by it being answered. Probably the close votes were from those wanting to see an example?

Answer (score 4):

One method uses window functions.  In standard SQL:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by clientid order by clientid)
fetch first 100 rows only;
```

In SQL Server, you would use `top (100)` if `fetch` is not available.

The `row_number()` will assign a value of "1" to one of the rows for each client.  These will appear first.  So, if there are 20 clients, then returning 20 rows will have one row per client.  With 100 rows, you will have 5 rows per client -- unless some of the clients have fewer than 5 rows.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean . . . One row for each client will have "1", another "2", and so on.  The "1"s are all output before the "2", so one record from all clients will be put in the result set before any second record for a client already in the result set.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that SQL :(

Comment: How can I have running total along with above conditions. I updated the question

Comment: @Mike . . . You should ask another question.  This answers the one you originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

say you have a table with 5000 records
RecordId,ClientId,.......

Select top 100 * from table where (Select count(*) from table t where t.RecordId = Table.RecordId) = 20